# Why isn't a state change affecting the display of options in a React Select component?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select for a dropdown. I am using an asynchronous call to fetch the options as you search, but I am not using the AsyncSelect component because I only want it to fetch after it has been focused (a lot on one page caused too much traffic).

Thus, I am using the basic Select component to do this: this.state.options is updated upon the fetch and is passed into the components "options" prop.
The problem is that the options list display becomes empty when this.state.options changes. I've printed this.state.options to console upon render to confirm that it does change to a correctly populated list when the search input changes, but the component shows "No options.".

Here are the example contents of this.state.options. This is correct behavior.

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { value: {…}, label: "Calcite Crystal Formation" }
​
1: Object { value: {…}, label: "Lithium Crystal Formation" }
```

If I un-focus then re-focus the component, the options list updates and will display the new options correctly. But otherwise it changes to display "No options," which does not reflect this.state.options. How can I make the options list update correctly? Or am I going about this wrong?

Here is (the relevant parts of) the component that uses the Select component:

```
import React, { Component }                 from 'react'
import Select, { components }               from 'react-select'
import { API_post }                         from '../../util_components/API'

class RelationalField extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.resetState()
    }
    resetState(){
        return {
            options: [],
            input: null
        }
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.options)
        let curr_value = undefined
        if(this.props.curr_value) curr_value = {label:(this.props.curr_value.title || this.props.curr_value.username), value:this.props.curr_value}
        return (
          <Select
            placeholder={this.state.input || ''}
            options={this.state.options}
            input={this.state.input}
            onFocus={() => this.loadOptions(this.state.input)}
            onInputChange={this.loadOptions.bind(this)}
            value={curr_value}
            getOptionLabel={this.renderOption.bind(this)}
            onChange={this.onSingleSelect.bind(this)}
          />
    }
    onSingleSelect(selection){
        if(selection && selection.value && selection.label) selection = selection.value
        this.props.handleChange({target:{name: this.props.fieldRealName, value: selection}})
    }
    loadOptions(query){
        if(query === this.state.input && this.state.options.length !== 0) return
        if(query == '') return
        if(query == null) query = ''
        var filtering = {
            start: 0,
            end: 25,
            object_types: [this.state.target_model].flat(),
            filter: [query]
        }
        if(this.props.known_alias_list){
            API_post('global-search', filtering, function(response){
                this.setState({
                    input: query,
                    options: response.data.objects.map(x=> {if(x.username){return {value: x, label:x.username}} 
                                                            else         return {value: x, label:x.title}})
                }, )
            }.bind(this), this)
        }
        
    }
    renderOption(option){
        if(!option || !this.props.known_alias_list) return null
        return (
            <table className='highlight-on-hover' style={{width: '100%'}}><tbody><tr>
               <td>{option.label}
               {Object.keys(this.props.known_alias_list).includes(option.value.id) && ' ('+this.props.known_alias_list[option.value.id]+')'}</td> 
               {option.value.image &&
                    <td><ObjectImage picture={option.value.image} 
                    style={option.value.username
                        ? {height: '25px', width: '25px', float: 'right', borderRadius: '50%'}
                        : {height: '25px', width: '25px', float: 'right'}}/></td>
                }
            </tr></tbody></table>
        )
    }
}

export default RelationalField
```

Comment: FYI I tried to parse this, set up a codesandbox to play around, tried to peek the source to see when Select itself re-renders, but didn't get too far. If you don't get too many answers, I recommend simplifying the example a bit more. You might even catch the problem while doing so. If this.state is showing the correct information in your render() call, I can't help but think the react-select component isn't re-rendering and that's where to look. You can also try looking at the react-select component with react dev tools to see what props the Select has. GL!

Comment: Thank you! The suggestion to look at the possible props with react dev tools helped me find the solution!

Comment: Great to hear... so it was probably some trick to get it to re-render? You can answer your own question and accept it for all to see in the future if you have time too

Comment: Yes! I was typing as I got your response :) It was a matter of finding the right prop to pass a custom render function for each option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, the problem was discovered to be because I was using a custom method to render each option.

Passing in this method to the "getOptionLabel" prop only worked upon the first render of the component, when I was focusing the component. Instead, this function should be passed to the "components" prop as the "Option" component function:

```
<Select
isSearchable
isClearable
placeholder={this.state.input || ''}
menuPlacement='auto'
options={option_list}
input={this.state.input}
onFocus={() => this.loadOptions(this.state.input)}
onInputChange={this.loadOptions.bind(this)}
value={curr_value}
// getOptionLabel={this.renderOption.bind(this)} << this is incorrect
classNamePrefix={'smartlab-select'}
onChange={this.onSingleSelect.bind(this)}
components={{
             SingleValue: this.BubbleLinkLabelSingle.bind(this), 
             animatedComponents: animatedComponents,
             Option: this.OptionDisplay.bind(this)
}}
/>

...

// previously known as "renderOption"
OptionDisplay = (option) => {
   if(!option || !this.props.known_alias_list) return null
   return (
      <table className='highlight-on-hover' {...option.innerProps}>
      <tbody><tr>
               <td>{option.label}</td> 
               {option.value.image &&
               <td><ObjectImage picture={option.value.image}/></td>
               }
       </tr></tbody></table>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is a PureComponent, it allows for re-rendering based on state changes after the initial render.

Some information about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: If you mean changing the parent class of this RelationalField component to "PureComponent" instead of "Component," I have just tried this and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: If the data is being set into the state which you confirmed to be the case per the console.log, then it is purely a rendering problem. I would try changing the Select component to PureComponent, or if it's a functional, passing the options props as a dependency in a useEffect hook.

Comment: I have now tried both of these options, but neither seemed to change the behavior described above. I'm thinking this problem is react-select specific and I might be missing some prop that I can't find in the react-select docs.